# Python AttributeError when importing module resolves after calling 'help()'

Tags: python

I'm getting started with packaging a Python library, and I'm experiencing odd behavior when trying to import a function. I built a wheel for this library and installed in my conda environment using pip. The structure of my library is:

```
|- setup.py
|- test_package
    |- __init__.py
    |- module1.py
    |- myutils.py
```

The `myutils.py` file contains a simple function:

```
def test_utils():
    print("utils test function is working correctly")
```

The following import works as expected:

```
from test_package import myutils
myutils.test_utils()
```

result:

```
utils test function is working correctly
```

However, the following import results in an error:

```
import test_package
test_package.myutils.test_utils()
```

result:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [1], in <cell line: 2>()
      1 import test_package
----> 2 test_package.myutils.test_utils()

AttributeError: module 'test_package' has no attribute 'myutils'
```

The odd behavior is that if I call `help()` after receiving the error above and then call the function again, it works as expected:

```
help('test_package.myutils.test_utils')

print("~~~~~ line break ~~~~~")

test_package.myutils.test_utils()
```

result:

```
Help on function test_utils in test_package.myutils:

test_package.myutils.test_utils = test_utils()

~~~~~ line break ~~~~~
utils test function is working correctly
```

I'm having difficulty understanding why using `from <package> import <module>` works while `import <package>` fails, and I'm definitely not understanding why `help()` resolves the AttributeError

Comment: A module is not automatically made an attribute of the package that contains it. `help` does quite a few things; adding that attribute appears to be one of them.

Comment: The similarity in syntax between attribute access and fully qualified module names does not help make the situation clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While some packages do automatically import their subpackages (usually for historical reasons, e.g. `import os` provides `os.path` to this day because it originally did so, and they don't want to break programs that rely on it), the recommendation is, and has been, to import the subpackages/submodules you rely on, not just the top-level packages (which are under no obligation to import their child packages).

If top-level packages had to import their hierarchies, a package with three subpackages, all expensive to load, but often used in isolation, would have to pay the expense of importing all three subpackages even when the script performing the import only needed one of them.

The correct way to solve this problem is to explicitly import the packages you need, changing:

```
import test_package
```

to:

```
import test_package.myutils
```

which will cause the subpackage to be imported, and allow `test_package.myutils.test_utils()` to work.

---

The reason `help` fixes things is that in the process of loading the documentation, it imports the subpackage. And the process of importing a subpackage attaches it to the parent package (a singleton shared by every location that imported the parent package). So `help('test_package.myutils.test_utils')`, internally, ends up performing `import test_package.myutils`, which attaches `myutils` to the cached `test_package` (an alias of which is in your main module), so when you ask for `test_package.myutils` again, it's found.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that behaviour, you need to add to `test_package/__init__.py`:

```py
import myutils
```

You are probably used to being able to do this in other libraries because they often add these imports to the relavent `__init__.py` files for your convenience. However, this is not the default behavior of python imports. The reason why is that the library author might want to allow easy access to certain submodules without recursively importing all submodules and taking a performance hit for it.

Just realize that the only things that you can import from a module are the things imported or defined *in that module*, whether the module is a directory `module/__init__.py` or a file `module.py`.

Comment: A side-note: There is a way to make this work without eagerly importing `myutils` on modern Python. As of Python 3.7, [you can define `__getattr__` on modules](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-562-customization-of-access-to-module-attributes), which would let you defer importing `myutils` until someone actually asked for it, but avoid paying the cost when no one asks for it. That said, the better solution is to stick to namespace packages (no `__init__.py` needed), and just have users import the actual packages they need.

Comment: While my original question was about the observed changing import behavior, this answer did help me import the sub-package automatically with the top-level package. This was originally confusing since many beginner tutorials just instruct you to create a blank `__init__.py` file

Comment: @astroChance: Yeah, those tutorials predate [PEP 420: Implicit Namespace Packages](https://peps.python.org/pep-0420/); there's no reason to provide blank `__init__.py` files nowadays, and it's actually a good idea not to provide them period (namespace packages mean that code sharing a top-level package can be installed as multiple packages without conflicting; if the `spam` PyPI package provides `corporatename.spam`, and `eggs` provides `corporatename.eggs`, without a `__init__.py` in either, they can be installed in different locations within `sys.path` and still leave both accessible.